# php array_keys search value by arrray?

Tags: php

My array looks like:

```
$arr =>
     (
       [0] => 2575
       [1] => 2570
       [2] => 0
       [3] => 2575
     )
```

And I want to be able to use the array_keys method to search for multiple keys, so I'm trying to get it work using an array as the search value but can't get it to work.

```
$keys = array_keys($arr, ['2575','2570']);
```

to return

```
  Array
     (
       [0] => 0
       [1] => 1
       [2] => 3
   )
```

Is it possible with array_keys to get the above function to work without calling it twice for each value?

Comment: You can't have multiple of the same keys in an associative array

Comment: But you have an array which keys are arrays with one item. And you are trying to use array_keys with the values not keys

Comment: I pretty doubt you have the source array as you described. Keys must be unique and you have multiple `1`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can do the same with two simple function calls:

```
$arr = [2575,2570,0,2575];

$search = ['2575','2570'];

$result = array_keys(array_intersect($arr, $search));
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
    0 => int 0
    1 => int 1
    2 => int 3
```